# Proving shift operator on infinite dimensional Hilbert space is not unitary

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, unitarity

Consider an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis:
$$\{\lvert{n}\rangle\}, n = 0,1,2,...$$
Define a shift operator such that $$S\lvert{n}\rangle = \lvert{n+1}\rangle$$

Then find a representation of $S$ in terms of the above basis and prove that it is not unitary namely:
$$S^\dagger S = 1 \ne S S^{\dagger}$$

I tried to consider the representation $$S = \sum_{n} \lvert n+1 \rangle\langle n \lvert$$
$$S^{\dagger} = \sum_{n} \lvert n \rangle\langle n+ 1\lvert$$

But I'm not sure why $S S^{\dagger} \ne 1.$

Comment: You should be able to compute $SS^\dagger$ explicitly with little effort. What do you get when you try?

Answer (score 2):

Look at what happens with $|0\rangle$ when you try to apply $SS^{\dagger}$ to it. The summation in the last two expressions run from $n=0$. As a result, the combination $SS^{\dagger}$ does not contain a term that operates on $|0\rangle$.